# Is the bound between the matrix 2-norm and the max-norm tight?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

It is well known that $\|A\|_2\leq\sqrt{mn}\|A\|_{\max}$ for an $m\times n$ matrix. Is this bound tight? i.e which matrix $B$ satisfies $\|B\|_2=\sqrt{mn}\|B\|_{\max}$ (note the equality)? And is there such an example for any $m,n$?

Comment: Take all entries  equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

Take any vector $v^t$, with $v=(q,\dots,q)\in\mathbb R^n$.

Then

$$\sqrt{n\cdot 1}\|v^t\|_{max}=\sqrt{n}|q|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n q^2}=\|v^t\|_2.$$

Comment: I don't see the relation... You are referring to vector norms while I asked about matrix norms (I don't think the matrix max-norm is induced from some vector-norm). Am I missing your point?

Comment: A vector of length $n$  is an $n\times 1$ matrix (or $1\times n$, depending on how you write it)